# Holidays effect in FBProphet model is all zero

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I have a Prophet model that predicts the shipments of a company.  When I add the special events (promotions and holidays), they seem to have no effect on the model's predictions. Am I doing something wrong? In all the examples I checked, the holidays always have an effect on the Prophet model.

```
from fbprophet.make_holidays import make_holidays_df
import datetime
country_name= 'ES'
festivos=make_holidays_df([2017,2018,2019,2020],'ES')
festivos['dia']=0
for index, row in festivos.iterrows():
    festivos.loc[index,"dia"]='Festivo ' + str(datetime.datetime.weekday(festivos.iloc[index]["ds"]))
festivo2=pd.DataFrame({'holiday':festivos['dia'],'ds':festivos['ds'],'lower_window':-9,'upper_window':1,})
festivo1=pd.DataFrame({'holiday':festivos['holiday'],'ds':festivos['ds'],'lower_window':-9,'upper_window':1,})
festivo=pd.concat((festivo2,festivo1))
festivo=pd.DataFrame(festivo)
festivo
```

```
ph_home = Prophet(holidays=festivo)
ph_home.add_country_holidays(country_name='ES')
ph_home.fit(home_train)
fut_home= ph_home.make_future_dataframe(periods=6,freq='M')
pred_home=ph_home.predict(fut_home)
fig1 =ph_home.plot(pred_home)
a = add_changepoints_to_plot(fig1.gca(), ph_home, pred_home)
fig1=ph_home.plot_components(pred_home)
pd.concat([home_train.set_index('ds')['y'],pred_home.set_index('ds')['yhat']],axis=1).plot(figsize=(15,10))
```

[Holidays effect in my Prophet model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT8Fa.png)

[The DataFrame I am using to train the prophet model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7F5H.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?  I used your code with the FBProphet example data and it worked as you expected.

Comment: The data I am using has the proper shape requested by the prophet model I guess:

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its due to your monthly aggregation.  See the last note [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/non-daily_data.html).

`With data that has been aggregated to weekly or monthly frequency, holidays that don’t fall on the particular date used in the data will be ignored`